# Reusing a procedural method with one additional step added conditionally

Tags: ruby

I have a process in my application that requires I take an additional step from the 'usual' process.

Let's say I have a class/method like this:

```
    class ImportProcessor
     attr_reader : file

     def initialize(file)
       @file = file
     end

     def process
       validate_file(file)
       file_set = split_file(file)
       import_files(file_set)
     end
   end
```

That class processes the files I want to import. Now let's say I need to add another step to the process.

Now my #process method would need to look something like this:

```
def process
  validate_file(file)
  file_set = split_file(file)
  api_processing(file)
  import_files(file_set)
end
```

As you can see the only difference is one extra method call inside the #process method. Is there a pattern I should be using to accomplish this, or something else you would recommend?

One idea I had was to create a subclass of the ImportProcessor class for each file that I import so that I could add a method call to the ImportProcessor#process method via passing in a lambda.

Something like this:

```
class File1 < ImportProcessor
  def initialize(file)
    super(file)
  end

  def process
    super(lambda {|file| api_processing(file)})
  end

  private

  def api_processing(file)
    ApiProcessor.new(file).process
  end
end
```

And the ImportProcessor class would now look something like this:

```
   class ImportProcessor

    attr_reader : file
        def initialize(file)
          @file = file
        end

        def process(api_processor=nil)
          validate_file(file)
          file_set = split_file(file)
          api_processor.call(file) if self.is_a?(File1)
          import_files(file_set)
        end
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add an argument to your method?

```
 def process(run_some_other_method=false)
   validate_file(file)
   file_set = split_file(file)
   import_files(file_set)
   some_other_method(file) if run_some_other_method
 end
```

Then call it like this:

```
process # runs like normal since run_some_other_method defaults to false
process(true) # run with added method
```